# UICollectionView triggers pagination without scrolling

Tags: ios, swift, pagination, uicollectionview

I want to achieve a smooth pagination experience in UICollectionView. The idea is simple: trigger an API call when the last cell of collectionView is reached.

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

if indexPath.row == dataGroup.data.count-1{
        
        print("last cell visible" )

        self.isPaginating = true
        Service.shared.fetchData(page: self.page) { rawData, error in
            if let error = error{
                print("error while fetching app groups", error)
                return
            }
            sleep(2)
            if let data = rawData{
                self.dataGroup?.data += data.data
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.collectionView.reloadData()
                }
                self.page+=1
                self.isPaginating = false
            }
        }
    }

 //returning cells

}
```

Even though I don't scroll the collectionView, `if indexPath.row == dataGroup.data.count-1` becomes `true` and the API call is triggered. What can be the cause?

PS. I observe the `data.count` and pagination stops when all the data is loaded. I just removed it to simplify the code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Try to move your code in

```
collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
             willDisplay cell: UICollectionViewCell, 
               forItemAt indexPath: IndexPath)
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionviewdelegate/1618087-collectionview

And add check like :

```
    if collectionView.indexPathsForVisibleItems.lastObject.row == dataGroup.data.count-1. { 
do something
}
```